# How can I write this as a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a function in my App.js to test if it runs or not but want to turn it into its own component class. I tried it with `class ... ectends React.component` end the export expression but it simply didn't compile.

The function is supposed to be a Testversion for a quiz with 3 testquestion to test if the structure works. I want to be able to reach the function with:

```
  <Route exact path="/play_quiz" component={play_quiz}></Route>
```

from the index.js which isn't fully implemented yet.

````
import './play_quiz.css';

export default function () {
    const questions = [
        {
            questionText: 'testquestion1',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'correct answer', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'testquestion2',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'correct answer', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'testquestion3',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'correct answer', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },

    ];

    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const [showScore, setShowScore] = useState(false);
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

    const handleAnswerOptionClick = (isCorrect) => {
        if (isCorrect) {
            setScore(score + 1);
        }

        const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if (nextQuestion < questions.length) {
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        } else {
            setShowScore(true);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div className='quiz-window'>
            {showScore ? (
                <div className='score-section'>
                    korrekt beantwortet: {score} von {questions.length}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <div className='question-section'>
                        <div className='question-count'>
                            <span>Frage {currentQuestion + 1}</span>/{questions.length}
                        </div>
                        <div className='question-text'>{questions[currentQuestion].questionText}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='answer-section'>
                        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
                            <button onClick={() => handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.isCorrect)}>{answerOption.answerText}</button>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}```
````

Comment: What have you tried on your own already? What isn't working? Does it *need* to be converted to a class-based component? What is the benefit in doing so?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Try to implement `index.js` and import it first then rephrase your question

Comment: well, its a group project and "my part" is this function. I tried to replace the function setup with 
class play_quiz extends Component {  and the export default play_quiz at the end but it wont compile

Comment: Is the functional component not working and that is why you are trying to convert to a class-based component? In React a component is a component, so what is the purpose of converting a functional component to a class-based one? Is the conversion part of the project? You should attempt this on your own first, then if you are stuck, update your question with an example of your code and description about what isn't working as expected.

Comment: This is turning into a rat hole. I don't think your component being a functional or class-based component has anything to do with any perceived or actual issue you face, whatever it may be. Saying something isn't working and not explaining it or showing what you or your code is doing is a waste of time. Part of asking for help on SO is doing your due diligence to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your issue. It shouldn't turn into a game of 20 questions and the topic shouldn't shift. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this component does actually works as expected and you just want to convert it to a Class Component instead of using react-hooks. I don't know actually what are the benefits of that, I will just do it for you, so here is my solution:

```
import './play_quiz.css';
import React from "react"

export class function extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      questions: [
        {
            questionText: 'testquestion1',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'correct answer', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'testquestion2',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'correct answer', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },
        {
            questionText: 'testquestion3',
            answerOptions: [
                { answerText: 'correct answer', isCorrect: true },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
                { answerText: 'wrong answer', isCorrect: false },
            ],
        },

    ],
    currentQuestion: 0,
    showScore: false,
    score: 0
    }
  };  
  


    handleAnswerOptionClick = (isCorrect) => {
        if (isCorrect) {
            this.setState({score: score + 1});
        }

        const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if (nextQuestion < questions.length) {
          this.setState({
            currentQuestion: nextQuestion
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            showScore: true
          })
        }
    };

    const {showScore, score, questions, currentQuestion} = this.state;

    return (
        <div className='quiz-window'>
            {showScore ? (
                <div className='score-section'>
                    korrekt beantwortet: {score} von {questions.length}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <div className='question-section'>
                        <div className='question-count'>
                            <span>Frage {currentQuestion + 1}</span>/{questions.length}
                        </div>
                        <div className='question-text'>{questions[currentQuestion].questionText}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='answer-section'>
                        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
                            <button onClick={() => this.handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.isCorrect)}>{answerOption.answerText}</button>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It is indeed working fine, but i was told that i cant call it from another class if its not a component class(i just imported it as an app with import App from './play_quiz';

Comment: Interesting, I believe you can just call it and it doesn't matter the structure of it, actually recently I read an article on medium.com about why we shouldn't use Class Components in react.js 
I highly recommend you read this topic, unfriendly I don't have a URL so you have to google it your self

Comment: @nikva Can't call *what* from another class? The functional component? As I said, in react, a component is a component, they have the same surface API in JSX.

Comment: it didnt work because i tried to route to it with       <Route exact path="/play_quiz" component={play_quiz}></Route>. How do i route to it then if i keep my original structure?